# @mention with text or just text on its own

Tags: php, ajax, json, str-replace

I have a value or newmsg sent through my div textarea and this can consist of @mention text
or just text depending on what the user inputs into the status updater.

Problem I'm facing is that when I add the str_replace code to convert the @mention + text, is that it will post anything with an @mention + text, but not post a normal status with just text on its own. I need my php script to post both.

If it has an @metion + text post

```
<a href="profile.php?username='.isset($_POST['red']).'">@mention</a> Hi my name is Dave
```

Or if its just text without @mention

```
Hi my name is Dave
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['toid'])){
    if($_POST['toid']==""){$_POST['toid']=$_SESSION['id'];}


if(isset($_POST['newmsg'])&&isset($_POST['toid'])&&isset($_POST['privacy'])&&isset($_POST['red'])){


$_POST['newmsg']=str_replace('@'.isset($_POST['red']).'','<a href="profile.php?username='.isset($_POST['red']).'">'.isset($_POST['red']).'</a>', $_POST['newmsg']);

$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=".$_SESSION['id']."";
$query=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
 date_default_timezone_set($row['timezone']);
$date=date('y:m:d H:i:s');
        if($_POST['toid']==$_SESSION['id']){
            user_core::create_streamitem("1",mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_SESSION['id']),mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['newmsg']),mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['privacy']),mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['toid']),mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$date));
        }else{
            user_core::create_streamitem("3",mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_SESSION['id']),mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['newmsg']),mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['privacy']),mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['toid']),mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$date));
        }
    }

}
```

AJAX

```
var content = $(this).children("#toid").val();
            var newmsg= $(this).children("#newmsg").text();
           var username = $(".red").attr("href");
            var privacy = $("#privacy").val();
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insert.php",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            data: { toid: content, newmsg: newmsg, privacy: privacy, red: username }, 
            success: function(response){ }
```

I still have to escape my variables to prevent sql injection also.

Comment: Sidenote: `</a<` in your posted code should read as `</a>`

Comment: That is just an example link. but will update it.

Comment: sorry,just ask..what this code do ? $_POST['newmsg']==$_POST['newmsg'];

Comment: @dave I was just about to say the same thing ^^^ `$_POST['newmsg']==$_POST['newmsg'];` *Technically speaking*, you're comparing using `==` instead of assigning `=` yet as Randyka asked, what is that supposed to do?

Comment: I should of removed that actually. I was testing to see if it would work with that, but it didn't make any difference. I will remove it.

Comment: You also have a few `&isset` which should be `&& isset` @dave

Comment: @Fred-ii- rectified, still the same issue.

Comment: It was surely a contributing factor. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. Plus, check to see what your HTML source reads out as. That should be of some help also.

Comment: I always use `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);`

Comment: So as it stands with the php code above if I post a status with @mention and some text beside it, it always updates. But if I update with text alone the ajax fires the values and it just inputs the last inputted status and doesn't update the database with the new text. so I'm wondering whether and if else statement is needed. unsure because both :@mention with added text and text alone is under NEWMSG.

Comment: Normal text update

`newmsg ffff privacy 1 toid 33`

@mention update
`newmsg @me ffff privacy 1 toid 33  Red ME`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working. I removed the $_POST['red'] and wrapped it around the str_replace

```
if(isset($_POST['toid'])){
    if($_POST['toid']==""){$_POST['toid']=$_SESSION['id'];}


if(isset($_POST['newmsg'])&&isset($_POST['toid'])&&isset($_POST['privacy'])){

if(isset($_POST['red']){
$_POST['newmsg']=str_replace('@'.isset($_POST['red']).'','<a href="profile.php?username='.isset($_POST['red']).'">'.isset($_POST['red']).'</a>', $_POST['newmsg']);
}
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=".$_SESSION['id']."";
$query=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
 date_default_timezone_set($row['timezone']);
$date=date('y:m:d H:i:s');
        if($_POST['toid']==$_SESSION['id']){
            user_core::create_streamitem("1",mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_SESSION['id']),mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['newmsg']),mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['privacy']),mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['toid']),mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$date));
        }else{
            user_core::create_streamitem("3",mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_SESSION['id']),mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['newmsg']),mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['privacy']),mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['toid']),mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$date));
        }
    }

}
```